# Unit Testing with Cocos2d-x and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, cocos2d-x

Hey I am currently working on my first app using cocos2d-X.
I'd like to test it using a unit testing framework.
I tried to use googletest but didn't get very far because it kept throwing errors.
Has anyone found a good tutorial or knows how this can be achieved?
I don't mind using a different framework than googletest. Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you post the code that isn't working on googletest and the errors being thrown the community can help you.

Comment: I am not really sure yet if that is even the right approach. Anyway I am using the Mac (not iOS) helloCpp sample from the cocos2dx folder. I've added the googletest framework and got it to run. For now it successfully tests some dummy functions and now I'd like to include my helloWorldScene.h to my main.cpp test file. I am not able to build though since cocos2d.h cannot be found. Building the regular app is still possible though! I think the cocos2dx.xcodeproj is only targeted to my regular project but not my unit test one....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with Xcode's built in Testing Framework:

To set up the environment add “Cococa Touch Unit Testing Bundle” as a new Target to your project. Make sure the cocos-2dx’s library files also target your Test Files now. Simply browse to your project folder, re-add them and select both projects as their target. Next, link the required binaries with your Libraries under “Build Phases”.

It should include:
•   CoreGraphics
•   AV Foundation
•   AudioToolbox
•   OpenAL
•   OpenGLES
•   CoreData
•   Libsqlite3
•   QuartzCore
•   SenTestingKit
•   UIKitFramework
•   Libcurl (This might not appear automatically when you click ‘+’, simply search in project folder and add it manually)

Under “Build Settings” change the following:

•   Build Active Architecture Only: YES
•   iOS Deployment Target : iOS 5.0
•   Strip Style: All Symbols
•   Skip Install: NO
•   Other linker Flags: -lxml2 –lz
•   Force Package Info Generation: YES
•   Add (don’t delete any existing paths) to Framework Search Path: "$(SYSTEM_APPS_DIR)/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks" 
•   “Symbols Hidden by Default”: Debug: NO / Release : YES
•   C++ Language Dialect: Compiler Default
•   C++ Standard Library: Compiler Default
•   Objective-C ARC: NO
•   Empty Loop Bodies: NO
•   Uninitialized Variables: NO
•   Duplicate Method Definition: NO

Now import the cocos2d-X header file to your Unit Test file. The Unit Test’s .m File Type must be changed to Objective-C++ Source.
You should now be able to test your code.